# How do I set up OpenGL libraries on a Mac?

Tags: c++, opengl, xcode4, osx-lion

I would like to be able to go through a lesson on OpenGL so that I may learn to use OpenGL.  This means that I need to be able to compile and run the programs myself, so that I may play around with them and begin making my own OpenGL projects.  I can't do this if I can't install and include libraries that the lesson is using.  So, I need either:

- a lessons with instruction, for OSX, on how to install the libraries
  that the lesson uses
- a lesson that only teaches with the libraries that come with
  OSX (`GLUT` and `OpenGL`).

From what I have seen around the web, it appears that GLEW is the most used library with these lessons so instruction on how to install that would be top priority.  However, if there is another lesson that uses another library and you know how or have a link on how to set that library up for Mac, I would see that as a helpful answer.

Finally, overall, I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how they have their Mac set up with OpenGL, or point me to a tutorial that works with Macs.

Here are the tutorials I have been looking at:

- http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/
- http://www.cprogramming.com/graphics-programming.html

I have been able to get the headers `GLUT/GLUT.h` and `OpenGL/gl.h` which I think are OpenGL's main header files so, alternatively, if there is a lesson out there that only relies on these two headers (or any headers in the GLUT.framework or the OpenGL.framework included with OS X Lion) that would work just fine for me.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707667/how-do-i-set-up-an-opengl-project-using-xcode-4-2-in-c

Comment: @mydogisbox Just a note: This question is not just looking for a way to set up the basic OpenGL headers (I am able to do that) as the question this question was linked to is asking, it's looking for a solution so that I can efficiently learn OpenGL,  whether that be in a way that I find out how to build and include the libraries that are necessary so that I am able to follow along the lesson, or so that I am linked to a lesson that uses the libraries that are already include with OSX (glut and standerd OpenGL).

Comment: So you're looking for something like this: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/

Comment: Read more closely, realized you wanted the opposite of what I said.

Comment: @mydogisbox I have the basic GLUT and OpenGL libraries set up. I'm looking for a lesson that will teach me OpenGL with just these two libraries or a way to set up libraries like GLEW so that I can follow along with the tutorials that I listed.  *I want to be able to follow along a tutorial and run the examples myself and not have any issues.*  I have not found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install most needed development libraries for os X, install fink and then use fink to install everything else:

[Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/index.php?phpLang=en)

[Fink Glew page](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=glew)

As an added bonus [here](http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php?title=3d_Engine_Programming_Tutorials) are some GLUT tutorials (although for an older version of Xcode).

Comment: Thank you.  This is the sort of answer I was looking for :)  Sorry my question was unclear

Comment: If this question doesn't answer your question you should say what is missing, otherwise you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't been on SO for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need but i'll give you the basics for running an opengl/glut-based program using Xcode.

1. Create a new empty project, name it whatever you want
2. Under the project menu click "**New Target**"
3. On the left menu select "**Cocoa**", then click "**Application**", name it whatever you want
4. You should have a new window called "Target *'your-program's-name'* info"
5. Under the tab "**Build**" scroll all the way down to "**GCC_PREFIX_HEADER**", double click the value (wich should be something like **"$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h"**, delete this line, click ok.
6. Close the info window
7. Right click your project's name, click **Add** > **Existing frameworks** > Select "**OpenGL.framework**", click **add**.
8. Again, right click your project's name, click **Add** > **Existing frameworks** > Select "**GLUT.framework**", click **add**.
9. Right click your project's name, click **Add** > **New File** > under the "**C and C++**" tab, select **C++ file**, click next, name it whatever you want. (make sure it's being added to your project and target), click finish.
10. You're now ready to build and run any c++ project using OpenGl.framework and GLUT.framework

-You can use command + enter for building and running and command + shift + enter for closing an active window.

-When you require input from the user you should run it from terminal, compile like this:

"*gcc -o func2d func2d.c -framework carbon -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT*"

where func2d is the name of your application executable and func2d.c is the c file used

The imports required in case you don't have them are:

```
OpenGL/gl.h
OpenGL/glu.h
GLUT/glut.h
stdlib.h
```